# How to describe a person 'who's got firm opinion in life which is independent of others' and confident!"

Tags: vocabulary, expressions

Is "She is her own woman" typically used to deliver what I wrote in the title means? Or is there any better expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to describe this quality as a positive or a negative.  Some positive expressions:

> She is a free-thinker.
>
> She is a free spirit.
>
> She's an independent woman.
>
> She does it her way. (as in the famous [Frank Sinatra song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bYwKp2FJro))
>
> She carves her own path (through the world)

and various others.  Some negative expressions:

> It's her way or the highway (meaning, either do it how she says to do it or leave)
>
> She's stubborn as a mule.
>
> She's set in her (own) ways.
>
> She can be pigheaded

and various others.